# How to set all pages of a Fireworks CS4 document to PNG?

Tags: png, export, fireworks

I've a Fireworks CS4 document containing multiple pages. The File > Export > Pages to Files feature generates GIFs but I want PNGs instead. How can I change this setting for all pages avoiding to go through each page and manually change this setting?

Answer (score 10):

#### To Export All pages in preferred image format (in our case as PNG):

**Set all pages to export as PNG:**

- select all pages in Window > Pages (shortcut F5)
- in Window > Optimize (F6) setup your preferred image format (in our case PNG).
- all pages are now set to export as PNG files.

**Now export (save) all pages:**
Note: page names/titles, see/edit them in Window > Pages (F5), are used as names for exported files

*Solution **FIREWORKS CS4***

- File > Export.. (Ctrl+Shift+R)
- IMPORTANT: uncheck "Current page only" on bottom of Export window.

*Solution **FIREWORKS CS5***

- select pages > rightclick > Export all

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, where Fireworks kept exporting .gifs even when I specified PNG (use the "Export Wizard" in *File > Export Wizard*.

What was odd is that my index page (page 1) was a PNG, and the other pages were GIF. I have no idea why they defaulted as GIF, but that was the culprit. See attached image, the document type is specified there and it has to be PNG.

Image: http://davormiksic.com/iphone_test/png_check.png

I believe you can make your file type PNG by "Save As" and choosing PNG. Otherwise, when I do "Create New" and start working, it is PNG by default for me. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the answer you want, but, having those gif files, you could do a batch process, like:

**Fireworks CS5:**

- File > Batch Process...
- Select all files you want
- Select "Export" as batch option, and choose "custom" from setting tab
- Select the PNG format you want, or any other in the format tab
- Set the location for the files
- and then batch =)